# WP API querying a custom post type and a custom field

Tags: rest-api

I'm developing a site that displays results from a local running race from the past 15 years or so.

I have a custom post type called `result` with several custom fields.

Each result looks like:

`result: { year, position, name, guntime, chiptime, class, classplace}`

The results look like this:

[image]

I'm pulling in these results via a live-search interface that fetches from `wp-json/wp/v2/result?search=SEARCH_TERM`

So `/wp-json/wp/v2/result?search=colin` gets me all of the Colins in my data.

I have two questions about my setup:

1. How do I add a custom field to search on in my query? IE: **I want everyone named Colin who ran in 2018**. I've read that that the `filter` param was removed before the plugin was merged, so looks like that won't work. I think It used to be as simple as `filter[year]=2018`, but that approach is no longer possible.

   2. I'm wondering more broadly if this whole setup will standup to any real-world traffic. I've got my live-search input debounced, but I'm still going to be doing a ton of api requests. **Good news**: There is no post content to search through (all the fields are just numerical data). **Bad News**: I'm still searching about 50,000 post titles looking for matches each time I live-search.

Advice greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time!